# jax woes (on an NVDIA DGX box, no less)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jax

I am trying to run jax on an nvidia dgx box, but am failing miserably, thus:

```
>>> import jax
>>> import jax.numpy as jnp
>>> x = jnp.arange(10)
2021-10-25 13:00:05.863667: W 
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:80] Couldn't 
get ptxas version string: INTERNAL: Couldn't invoke ptxas --version
2021-10-25 13:00:05.864713: F 
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nvptx_compiler.cc:435] 
ptxas returned an error during compilation of ptx to sass: 'INTERNAL: Failed to 
launch ptxas'  If the error message indicates that a file could not be written, 
please verify that sufficient filesystem space is provided.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your CUDA installation is not configured correctly, and can generally be fixed by ensuring that the CUDA toolkit binaries (including `ptxas`) are present in your `$PATH`. See https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/6843 and https://github.com/google/jax/issues/7239 for responses to users reporting similar issues.

Comment: Thanks! My confusion stems somewhat from the fact that this is a DGX box, so I would have thought it would come from the factory configured properly. But no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you need to install `nvidia-driver`, `cuda` and `cudnn` correctly and the risky command here would be: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` avoid this command if you have installed those 3 already.

the way which works for me:

- Install `nvidia-driver`: follow [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-multiple-cuda-cudnn-versions-in-ubuntu-fcb6aa5194e2) and proper version also. you can try `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` in ubuntu
- Install `cuda` : for finding which cuda version works for you run `nvidia-smi` and on top-left you will see compatible version for the cuda then go [nvidia cuda archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) and follow the instructions there.
  at this step you should be able to see cuda foder when you type `ls /usr/local`. if you want to install header also you can find useful command from [nvidia installation guide for cuda](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).
- Install `cudnn` which means copy paste some files into `/usr/local/cuda` directory if you go through [cuDNN nvidia guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) you would find the best way.
- the last step you need to refer to the cuda path (`/usr/local/cuda` if you follow above). for example if you use docker you need to mount it like [here](https://medium.com/@adityathiruvengadam/cuda-docker-%EF%B8%8F-for-deep-learning-cab7c2be67f9). avoid install nvidia-cuda-toolkit it would remove your previous installation and instead you can install it in conda-env by `conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc` which doesn't interfere your cuda installation.